# How to automatically remove unneeded line breaks in Intellij Idea's code cleanup

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just started using IntelliJ IDEA and went through the automatic code clean-up options. It gives me the option to remove unneeded white lines, but I can't find an option to automatically remove unneeded break for example here:

`System.out.println("this, sir "
   + "is an unneeded line break");`

Does this feature exist, if yes, where?

Comment: A well-phrased regex search and replace can do that, but I'd manually review each one before it happens.

Comment: Good idea, would be wonderful though if it would happen automagically. You sure this is the only way?

Comment: No, not sure if its the only way or not -- just thought I'd toss out an idea that would work if you didn't find anything better.   I'm constantly cleaning up broken formatting...

Comment: If someone has the answer I'd be interested as well... Versions 9 and lower handled that well, but 10+ suck at text formatting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under **Preferences -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces** there is an option called **Keep when reformatting** with a checkbox for **Line breaks**.

If you uncheck it IDEA will do what you want.

Comment: It is actually now called **Keep line breaks** under **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> {programming language} -> Other**. I really needed to uncheck this option because it was breaking down my Ruby code...